# What are the scenarios that cause postgres to do a seq scan instead of an index scan?

Tags: postgresql

I've run into a very strange issue that has come up multiple times. When I create a database and initially query against a table, the plain command tells me to use index scan.

But during the development process, maybe (I'm not sure) some modifications were made to the table, or some index modifications were made. Later I found that for the same query, it no longer uses Index scan.
If I delete this table and rebuild it, I find the same table and index structure, it starts using index scan again.

I know there are some scenarios, such as when the scan results in very many rows, postgres may directly use seq scan for optimization. But my query could always return only 0 or 1 rows.

I also know that index scan can be more costly in some scenarios due to startup time, but this is clearly not that scenario here either.
Can anyone help me with a clue that I can investigate?

```sql
testdb=> \d tabverifies; 
                             Table "public.tabverifies" 
 Column |   Type   | Collation | Nullable |                 Default 
--------+----------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------ 
 vid    | integer  |           | not null | nextval('tabverifies_vid_seq'::regclass) 
 lid    | integer  |           | not null | 
 verify | integer  |           | not null | 
 secret | text     |           | not null | 
Indexes: 
    "tabverifies_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (vid) 
    "tabverifies_lid_verify_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (lid, verify) 
Foreign-key constraints: 
    "tabverifies_lid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (lid) REFERENCES tablogins(lid) 
 
testdb=> explain select * from tabverifies where vid=1000; 
                         QUERY PLAN 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
 Seq Scan on tabverifies  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=1 width=44) 
   Filter: (vid = 1000) 
(2 rows)
```

```sql
testdb=> \d tabverifies; 
                             Table "public.tabverifies" 
 Column |   Type   | Collation | Nullable |                 Default 
--------+----------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------ 
 vid    | integer  |           | not null | nextval('tabverifies_vid_seq'::regclass) 
 lid    | integer  |           | not null | 
 verify | integer  |           | not null | 
 secret | text     |           | not null | 
Indexes: 
    "tabverifies_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (vid) 
    "tabverifies_lid_verify_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (lid, verify) 
Foreign-key constraints: 
    "tabverifies_lid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (lid) REFERENCES tablogins(lid) 
 
sigserverdb=> explain select * from tabverifies where vid=1; 
                                     QUERY PLAN 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 Index Scan using tabverifies_pkey on tabverifies  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=44) 
   Index Cond: (vid = 1) 
(2 rows)
```

Comment: In the first plan, the optimizers assumes there is only one row in the table `tabverifies`

Comment: Then the statistics might be out of date. You can verify that using `explain (analyze, buffers)` instead of a "plain" explain. to update the statistics, use `analyze tabverifies;`

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name I'll try it when I meet again.